# Can we add OneTouchExpansable button on Javafx SplitPane like swing JSplitPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Can I add OneTouchExpandable button using css/java api libraries on JavaFX `SplitPane`. This option is already present in Swing `JSplitPane`. But I can't find that option on JavaFX API.

I think, can we add `Button` on SplitPane for doing auto collapse &/ expand.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API yet. You can either try to add a `Button` to `SplitPane` separator or file a feature request to http://javafx-jira.kenai.com