# Collapsible divider for split pane

Tags: javafx-2

in JavaFX 2.2 I want to use a split pane (or better: any component with two dividers) where the dividers can be collapsed / expanded again. Is there any Component which does this already for me (and I just don't get it) or do I have to implement this myself? Would you recommend to use Swing here?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: 
Maybe for a better imagination of my problem, the following information is neccessary: I want to split my contents vertically.

```
content | content | content
```

(where '|' are the dividers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX has a [SplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) to do this.

The pane does not include a button for collapsing and expanding the divider.  Either you need to program such a button yourself or the user can just manually drag the pane dividers.

See also: [Can we add OneTouchExpansable button on Javafx SplitPane like swing JSplitPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558063/can-we-add-onetouchexpansable-button-on-javafx-splitpane-like-swing-jsplitpane)

I would not recommend using Swing for this unless you have other important reasons to use Swing.

Comment: Hi Jewel, thanks for your answer, I thought so already, but I was not quite sure if I miss anything. Thanks for your quick response :)