# Set up OneTouchExpandable button on JavaFX SplitPane

Tags: java, javafx, splitpane

For my JavaFX GUI, I have to use some split panes. But a problem occurs: I have to make that when user click on a button on the split pane, this split pane hide one of this sides panes, and need one more click to reset this side pane as visible.

I found one other question like me here: [Can we add OneTouchExpansable button on Javafx SplitPane like swing JSplitPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558063/can-we-add-onetouchexpansable-button-on-javafx-splitpane-like-swing-jsplitpane), but old and no answer other than "No you can't".

I hope someone has any Idea about how to make this possible, or how to make something similar.

Thank you everyone !

Comment: You could try an approach similar to what James_D describes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209981/value-into-slider-thumb-in-javafx). You should probably target either `horizontal-grabber` or `vertical-grabber` (or maybe both?). See [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#splitpane)

Comment: Hum.. the problem is that a `Divider` (the thing that separate panes in JavaFx `SplitPane`) is not extending `Pane`. But I think there is a possibility to Override `SplitPane.Divider` and maky my own divider. **EDIT:** Arf impossible... `SplitPane.Divider` has all his methods final :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn’t resist giving this a try.  This isn’t a good solution, in that it ignores [NodeOrientation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/NodeOrientation.html), and doesn’t support accessibility (meaning, among other things, no keyboard control).  Also, the expansion buttons are irritatingly tiny, which makes them hard to click on.

But it’s something, at least.  Perhaps someone with more time can improve on it further.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleExpression;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OneTouchExpandable
extends Application {

    /**
     * Node properties key whose value is the saved divider position
     * just before user's one-touch-expand action is executed.
     */
    private static final Object ORIGINAL_POSITION = 
        OneTouchExpandable.class.getName() + ".originalPosition";

    /**
     * Percentage of divider thickness which one-touch button takes up,
     * as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.
     */
    private static final double ARROW_THICKNESS = 0.60;

    /**
     * Delta for comparing divider position (a double) with the min and max
     * divider values, which in practice do not reach 0.0 or 1.0.
     */
    private static final double END_TOLERANCE = 0.01;

    /**
     * Adds one-touch-expand buttons to a SplitPane's first divider.
     */
    public static void addOneTouchExpansion(SplitPane pane) {

        StackPane divider = (StackPane) pane.lookup(".split-pane-divider");
        Objects.requireNonNull(divider, "SplitPane's divider not present!"
            + " (you probably need to call this method from within"
            + " Platform.runLater)");

        DoubleBinding dividerPosition = Bindings.selectDouble(
            Bindings.valueAt(pane.getDividers(), 0), "position");

        Button colorSource = new Button();
        ColorAdjust disabledColor = new ColorAdjust(0, 0, 0.5, 0);

        BorderPane expander = new BorderPane();
        if (pane.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
            DoubleExpression scale =
                divider.heightProperty().multiply(ARROW_THICKNESS);
            DoubleExpression indent =
                divider.heightProperty().multiply((1 - ARROW_THICKNESS) / 2);

            Polygon upArrow = new Polygon(1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1);
            upArrow.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            upArrow.fillProperty().bind(colorSource.textFillProperty());
            upArrow.scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
            upArrow.scaleYProperty().bind(scale);
            upArrow.disableProperty().bind(
                dividerPosition.isEqualTo(0, END_TOLERANCE));
            upArrow.effectProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(upArrow.disabledProperty())
                    .then(disabledColor).otherwise((ColorAdjust) null));
            upArrow.setOnMouseClicked(e -> setDividerPosition(pane, 0));

            Polygon downArrow = new Polygon(1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0);
            downArrow.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            downArrow.fillProperty().bind(colorSource.textFillProperty());
            downArrow.scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
            downArrow.scaleYProperty().bind(scale);
            downArrow.translateXProperty().bind(scale.multiply(2).add(3));
            downArrow.disableProperty().bind(
                dividerPosition.isEqualTo(1, END_TOLERANCE));
            downArrow.effectProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(downArrow.disabledProperty())
                    .then(disabledColor).otherwise((ColorAdjust) null));
            downArrow.setOnMouseClicked(e -> setDividerPosition(pane, 1));

            Group expandButtonsPane = new Group(upArrow, downArrow);
            expandButtonsPane.translateYProperty().bind(indent);

            expander.setLeft(expandButtonsPane);
        } else {
            DoubleExpression scale =
                divider.widthProperty().multiply(ARROW_THICKNESS);
            DoubleExpression indent =
                divider.widthProperty().multiply((1 - ARROW_THICKNESS) / 2);

            Polygon leftArrow = new Polygon(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2);
            leftArrow.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            leftArrow.fillProperty().bind(colorSource.textFillProperty());
            leftArrow.scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
            leftArrow.scaleYProperty().bind(scale);
            leftArrow.disableProperty().bind(
                dividerPosition.isEqualTo(0, END_TOLERANCE));
            leftArrow.effectProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(leftArrow.disabledProperty())
                    .then(disabledColor).otherwise((ColorAdjust) null));
            leftArrow.setOnMouseClicked(e -> setDividerPosition(pane, 0));

            Polygon rightArrow = new Polygon(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2);
            rightArrow.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            rightArrow.fillProperty().bind(colorSource.textFillProperty());
            rightArrow.scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
            rightArrow.scaleYProperty().bind(scale);
            rightArrow.translateYProperty().bind(scale.multiply(2).add(3));
            rightArrow.disableProperty().bind(
                dividerPosition.isEqualTo(1, END_TOLERANCE));
            rightArrow.effectProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(rightArrow.disabledProperty())
                    .then(disabledColor).otherwise((ColorAdjust) null));
            rightArrow.setOnMouseClicked(e -> setDividerPosition(pane, 1));

            Group expandButtonsPane = new Group(leftArrow, rightArrow);
            expandButtonsPane.translateXProperty().bind(indent);

            expander.setTop(expandButtonsPane);
        }

        divider.getChildren().add(expander);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether double values are nearly equal.
     */
    private static boolean isNearly(double value,
                                    double target) {
        return (Math.abs(target - value) < END_TOLERANCE);
    }

    /**
     * Executes a one-touch expansion/contraction.
     *
     * @param pane SplitPane to perform expansion on
     * @param end farthest divider position in direction of expansion,
     *            either 0 or 1
     */
    private static void setDividerPosition(SplitPane pane,
                                           double end) {
        double oldPosition = pane.getDividers().get(0).getPosition();
        double start = 1 - end;
        if (isNearly(oldPosition, start)) {
            Object savedPosition = pane.getProperties().get(ORIGINAL_POSITION);
            if (savedPosition instanceof Number) {
                pane.setDividerPosition(0,
                    ((Number) savedPosition).doubleValue());
            } else {
                pane.setDividerPosition(0, 0.5);
            }
        } else if (!isNearly(oldPosition, end)) {
            pane.getProperties().put(ORIGINAL_POSITION, oldPosition);
            pane.setDividerPosition(0, end);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays test window.  Invoke application with 'vertical' as first
     * command-line argument to use a vertical SplitPane.
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Node child1 = createChild("Child 1");
        Node child2 = createChild("Child 2");

        SplitPane pane = new SplitPane(child1, child2);

        Collection<String> params = getParameters().getUnnamed();
        if (params.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.matches("[Vv].*"))) {
            pane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> addOneTouchExpansion(pane));

        stage.setTitle("One-Touch Expandable Demo");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a SplitPane child for test window.
     *
     * @param text text to show in node
     */
    private static Node createChild(String text) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        label.setMinWidth(0);
        label.setMinHeight(0);
        label.setMaxWidth(10000);
        label.setMaxHeight(10000);

        Label sizer = new Label(text);
        sizer.setVisible(false);
        sizer.setPadding(new Insets(100));

        sizer.setMinWidth(0);
        sizer.setMinHeight(0);
        sizer.setMaxWidth(10000);
        sizer.setMaxHeight(10000);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane(label, sizer);

        return pane;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, it is ugly xD But a good Idea ! For my project, I was re-making a `MySplitPane` using 3 panes, where the panes sizes can be changes using drag & drop on the 2nd pane of the `MySplitPane`; but is uglier than your solution ! (+1 ! I don't set answer as solved for now, I will wait a bit more time; and if no better answer appear, I will accept your answer as THE answer :P)

Comment: This one is a big ugly solution and I like it +1. Keep doing a good work.